# Splitting a rotating rect into smaller rects, how to rotate them to maintain the original big rect?

Tags: c++, rotation, sfml

I have a rectangle `r` with the size of 1536x720 which I rotate around its own center point `p(768, 360)`, which is easy enough with the built in sf::Sprite::rotate function

Now for unrelated reasons I have to split up the rectangle into 6 smaller rectangles (each sized 512x360).

These smaller rectangles are just the bigger rectangle `r` sliced up; they are positioned in such a way that "stitched together" they form the original rectangle (so it looks like it's still the original big rectangle)

**Illustration:** [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlRI3.png)

Since rectangle `r` was constantly rotating around its own center, splitting it into smaller rectangles has introduced the problem:

How do I rotate the stitched together rectangle (i.e. the smaller rectangles) around the original center `p` so that the original bigger rectangle is maintained? Is this even possible?

My English isn't that great so it's a bit tricky to explain. If you need more explaining I can draw the scenario in paint or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sf::Transformable::setOrigin` to set transform origin of each small rectangle to the center point of the large one.

Notice that it will become the origin of all transformations, e.g. small rectangles will scale with respect to that new center too, but probably that's the desired behavior.

Comment: Does this mean I still have to rotate each small rectangle like I would have rotated the big rectangle? So rotate each small rect and then use sf::Transformable::setOrigin?

Comment: Yep, only you `setOrigin` first and then rotate them as you like. I should say that usually you use transform hierarchy to achieve that, but for that you'll need to provide your actual code.

Comment: I see, thanks! I will try it now and see if I can get it working

Comment: It's working. I use the following code sf::Transform rot; rot.rotate(0.5, 768, 360); ... sprites_.at(i).setPosition(rot.transformPoint(sprites_.at(i).getPosition())); sprites_.at(i).rotate(0.5f);